# Can a Tourist from a VWP country carry (Rent/ Borrow) a gun in say Florida

Tags: usa, rental, activities, florida, firearms

Looking to find out if it is legal to borrow or rent a gun from an individual(s) or company to use to either visit the various gun ranges or wildlife hunting in Florida.

I have a shotgun licence in the UK for hunting etc... but looking to do something similar in Florida without falling foul of any gun carrying laws in transit to any gun range or hunting area?

I know various friends in the US that would lend the guns while there but are they required to be with me while attending any event? Basically not looking to be tethered to any third party...

Comment: Related: [Can a tourist buy a gun in the USA?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11341/3221)

Comment: Gun ranges generally provide guns; at least the ones I have visited will let you borrow a gun.

Comment: Don't think this is a duplicate - it would be only if being the (temporary) keeper of a firearm was considered the same as purchasing one.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67702/as-a-tourist-can-i-try-firearms-in-california

Answer (score 3):

I know link only answers are frowned upon, but [this](https://www.atf.gov/file/61841/download) and [this](https://www.atf.gov/file/83651/download) is your only answer. We are not lawyers or ATF agents to untangle this.

In short: if you are on a visa, then you are prohibited. If you are on a visa waiver, then you can continue with reading [this](http://britishexpats.com/forum/usa-57/non-immigrant-gun-law-florida-724986/).