# Can non-resident minors visiting the US go to shooting ranges in California?

Tags: usa, minors, chinese-citizens, firearms

I'm a 16-year-old from China and will be travelling to the states soon, is it allowed for non-resident minors to go to shooting ranges and operate firearms? (with adult supervision of course)

Comment: Will you have your parent or legal guardian with you?

Comment: California is not the place to try this. Nevada is more likely. See these questions: [1](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138383/can-a-tourist-shoot-a-gun-in-the-usa), [2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67702/as-a-tourist-can-i-try-firearms-in-california).

Answer (score 3):

Most places, by law, require that all children between the ages of 8 and 18 must be accompanied and directly supervised in the shooting booth by a parent or legal guardian.