# As a tourist, can one rent a gun in the US?

Tags: usa, legal, safety, firearms

A conversation this week at work reminded me of [this question about buying a gun in the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11341/101), and the question was asked if instead, you could rent instead of buying?

(Politics and amendments aside, whether guns are good or bad, just whether it's possible, legally)

Comment: I have rented various guns at a shooting range in GA for both myself (South African with H-1b) and my step-son (British with VWP) - so anecdotally yes it's certainly possible and probably legal ... These were for use on the premises, so I can't say if it's possible to rent one to carry out.

Comment: Do you mean rent and use outside of a shooting range?  As per @brhans renting at a shooting range is very common.

Comment: I don't know of anywhere in the US that you can rent a gun and remove it from the premises.

Comment: @PeterM yes, outside of a shooting range. Otherwise you're just picking up their gun and firing it. Rent would mean to carry on your person, like if you had bought one.