# How early can one apply for a new B1/B2 visa that is going to expire?

Tags: b1-b2-visas, visa-expiration

My US B1/B2 visa is going to expire in September 2020. I need to visit US for business + leisure (3 days for business and 3 days to explore surrounding cities) in April 2020. So when I enter US, my B1/B2 visa will be valid only for 5 months.

Here are my questions:

- Is it necessary to apply for a new B1/B2 visa before I travel?
- When is the earliest I can apply for a new B1/B2 visa? Can I apply it now (10 months before expiry)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you travel to the US prior 1 months of tourist visa expiry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2177/can-you-travel-to-the-us-prior-1-months-of-tourist-visa-expiry)

Comment: Linked question is a dup of part of the question, but not the entire question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is detailed in [Can you travel to the US prior 1 months of tourist visa expiry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2177/can-you-travel-to-the-us-prior-1-months-of-tourist-visa-expiry), US visas only need to be valid on the day that you enter the country. You can remain in the country after the date of the visa expiry.

There is no time limit on when you can apply for a new visa.  In general the US only allows you to have one visa of any type at a time, so when your new visa is approved they will stamp the old visa with a "Canceled Without Prejudice" stamp to record that visa as no longer being valid, and place the new visa in your passport.

Answer (score 1):

Your visa needs to be valid only on the day of your arrival in the US, so no, you do not need to apply for a new visa.

You can apply for a new visa at any time.  Your prior visa, if still valid, will be cancelled.